# Save prestashop order as text file

Tags: php, printing, sms, prestashop

Is there any way of saving the orders as a text(txt) file, after the customers order? because i am making a system for a sms printer, that need to print the orders out, after they out, but there is only 2 ways.. In a messed up string like so:

```
#55*2*27*Quantity,Order name%%%%,*;;39.00;;Firstname lastname;;;;7;;12232255*#
```

Like that, or the orders could be saved in a txt format, which the printer can read from..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you will need use hook "hookOrderConfirmation", that contains the object objOrder.

Regards